# How to plot C++ matices in matplotlibcpp?

Tags: c++, plot

For a while, I've been saving my data in the CSV file and plotting it in Python. But I want direct plots through C++. I came across this [C++ wrapper](https://github.com/lava/matplotlib-cpp). It's great, but I couldn't find the example for imshow() in the documentation. I couldn't understand the arguments required for this function. Could anyone help me with it?

**P.S** I also want to extend my plots to 2d animation. So, I am open to any other methods, too.

Comment: There is [literally an example for imshow](https://github.com/lava/matplotlib-cpp/blob/master/examples/imshow.cpp) on GitHub.

Comment: You obviously didn't find [this](https://github.com/lava/matplotlib-cpp/blob/master/examples/imshow.cpp)

Comment: If you are familiar with [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) and use C++17, you can have a look at [GnuPlotScripting lib](https://github.com/vincent-picaud/GnuPlotScripting).

Comment: @DYZ  Thank you for the reference. Can we not use this for a 2d matrix?

Comment: `z` in the example is a 2D matrix.

Comment: @DYZ Oh Ok, I am new to C++. I create a pointer for a matrix instead of vector so got confused with it.